# Update trigger MySQL giving syntax error

Tags: mysql

I want to create trigger to make update on table when inserting rows to other table, but I get a syntax error for this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER quantity AFTER INSERT ON sale_items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
update products set quantity = quantity -1 where id =(
SELECT product_id
FROM sale_items
ORDER BY id desc
LIMIT 1)
END;
```

Error:

> `#`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END' at line 7

Comment: We need to see the exact error.  Please update your question and paste in the error.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a silly trigger.  Why are you fetching the last update id using a subquery?  It should be available through `new`:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER quantity AFTER INSERT ON sale_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    update products
        set quantity = quantity - 1
        where id = new.product_id
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i think there should e semi colon after update command...
try using below trigger...

Comment: @AmanAggarwal . . . Although a semi-colon is good coding practice, it is not actually required in this context.

Comment: @AmanAggarwal was correct: "[***`statement_list`*** represents a list of one or more statements, each terminated by a semicolon (`;`) statement delimiter.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/begin-end.html)"  I can only send a link to [a successful sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2864b), so for proof just remove the `;` and see it fail.  However, one actually doesn't need a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement block here at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use proper Delimiter in your trigger , the correct code is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER quantity AFTER INSERT ON sale_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    update products set quantity = quantity - 1
        where id = new.product_id ;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```